# Setting rate limit for SSH connection to Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to use rsync (Linux) to upload files to my Google Cloud platform. It appears that there is a rate limit on how often I can do this. How can I relax this limit by means of a web interface?

Comment: I am not aware of a rate limit using rsync to a Google Cloud VM. What problem/error are you getting?

Comment: The problem has somehow resolved itself but thanks a lot for your response!